# Variable (results) captured by a closure before being initialized

Tags: arrays, swift3, closures, xcode8, google-places-api

I'm attempting to use a for loop and the Google Places API to look up an array of Place ID's like below. The code is mostly error free, however, I either have issues with my closures or the above error. I'm unsure which it is at this moment - any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
 let mexican = ["ChIJM8S9ACvoIogRmzYiLgzlP_g",
"ChIJwSHwoNTpIogRyElYj-kHC14",
"ChIJDWRMYifoIogR7S6U4tryodY",
"ChIJqSVd6yfoIogRmTgBSoO4Z0k",
"ChIJLacWlinoIogRVGYk-bZbGUE",
"ChIJSUC9S2zCIogRTKyiW0q_6tI"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

    var place: [String]

    var results: Array<Any>

    switch index.row
    {
    case 0 :
        place = international
    case 1 :
        place = american
    default :
         place = mexican
    }


    for id in place
    {
        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(id, callback: { (result, error) -> Void in

            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

           guard let result = result

            else
           {
            print("No place details for \(id)")
            return
            }
   results.append(result)
    })
 }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: you need to initialize results ,Use this statement var results = [Any]() instead of var results: Array<Any> , and see its behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is because you are not initializing the results array,
simple solution can be this

declare your results array like this

```
var results = [Any]()
```

I think you should do this:

you should declare results as instance variable like this outside `viewDidLoad` method

```
var results = [Any]()
```

Then use this variable inside closure as follows because I think you need this result in other parts of your code

```
self.results.append(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reach again, Stud. Ill have to look into initialization concepts. Anyways, while the LookUpID function error went away, when I attempt to enter " self.results.append(result)", I receive the Value of type FoodTwo has no member results on the same line.

Comment: @jonpeter Did you declare results outside viewDidLoad method? because this error is saying that the class you are in (which I think is FoodTwo) has no results array

Comment: Why am I not able to declare it inside viewDidLoad? Are global variables all declared about this function?

Comment: @jonpeter Yes you can , if you only change var results = [Any]() in your original code and use in closure as results.append(result) , your code will work, but I added in the answer that if you need this array say outside viewDidLoad , you should declare it as instance variable and in closure you access instance variable using self, if you still dont understand please ask